# How to find objects that reference another object in SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, authorize.net-cim

First of all I must apologize since I am very new when it comes to XML, RDF and SPARQL queries. All my knowledge is based on 3 days of much reading so it has not fully sunk in. Nevertheless, a problem I encountered when trying to query a large RDF file using Jena was **how to get all instances that are part of a superclass**?

Sorry if this is badly worded so here is an example. In my RDF file, there is always a main node:

The Main Node

and then there are objects that have this node as a resource like:

```xml
<cim:Connection rdf:ID="connection_1">
    <cim:Object.name>Connection Point 1</cim:Object.name>
    <cim:Connection.node rdf:resource="#main_node_1"/>
</cim:Connection>
```

or

```xml
<cim:Potential rdf:ID="potential_1">
    <cim:Object.name>Equal Potential 1</cim:Object.name>
    <cim:Potential.node rdf:resource="#main_node_1"/>
</cim:Connection>
```

Now I know how to query for any `rdf:type` and (a bit) how to graph query using SPARQL. What I want to do is 1st find the MainNode (which I already can) and then find all elements/objetcs/classes/instances that reference to this MainNode.

With my current attempts I can query for a `Connection` or `Potential` directly, but not for both. So the query returning all `Connection`s would be:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX cim: <http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#>
SELECT ?object
WHERE {
    ?object   cim:Connection.node ?mainNode . 
    ?mainNode cim:Object.name     "The Main Node" . 
}
```

and for all `Potential`s the query would be:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX cim: <http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#>
SELECT ?object
WHERE {
    ?object   cim:potential.node  ?mainNode . 
    ?mainNode cim:Object.name     "The Main Node" . 
}
```

Yet I need to extract both and do not want to use `UNION` since there may be more classes that I have not included. My attempt was to change the `?object` line to:

```
?mainNode cim:*.name "The Main Node" .
```

yet the asterisk `*` does not allow me to make any class available here. In fact, both `Connection` and `Potential` could be seen as children of a superclass that contains the variable `node`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I think you're asking for is any node that is one triple-connection away from the main node:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX cim: <http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#>
SELECT ?relationship ?object
WHERE {
  ?object   ?relationship  ?mainNode . 
  ?mainNode cim:Object.name     "The Main Node" . 
}
```

That query will tell you all of the nodes directly connected to the main node, and the URI of the connecting predicate.

If you only want *some* of the connections from related nodes to the main node, then you either need to enumerate them in a union, or add a `FILTER` clause to remove the ones that you don't want.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted! Didn't imagine it was that straight forward in the end. Thanks a lot